# NoSuchMethodError under test run with gradle

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to experimentally port a MAVEN java project to gradle. One of the problems I came across is failure to execute unit tests because of NoSuchMethodError happening at runtime (during execution). I'm calling `FileUtils.write()` method.

I modified my code to trace the class path available in the ClassLoader that loaded FileUtils class and I've got following:

```
C:/Sdk/gradle-2-7/lib/commons-io-1.4.jar
C:/Users/<me>/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/b1b6ea3b7e4aa4f492509a4952029cd8e48019ad/commons-io-2.4.jar
```

Out of that I see that there are 2 versions of commons-io in class path during test run and the one coming with gradle is the first and therefore has higher priority.

What is the root cause? How this can be fixed?

Actually, I expect no JARs to be available in classpath other than explicitly declared in dependencies of my gradle project.

---

**Update**: it seems that I've got an idea about the root cause - the project being tested is 'gradle plugin' and to compile it in gradle i have to specify following in `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile gradleApi()
}
```

And this seeps to capture all gradle dependencies into my project. Though i still do not see the way to fix it:

- I can't remove it because the project wont compile
- I can't exclude something because gradle does not support this for `gradleApi()` (see http://gradle.1045684.n5.nabble.com/exclude-some-dependencies-from-gradleApi-dependency-td5712103.html).
- I can't add only those gradle jar's I really need as dependencies - i do not see any way to reference them explicitly in compile dependencies, i do not see any public repository containing these artifacts. Note: for MAVEN build I've manually uploaded them into local MAVEN repo.

Comment: Is the issue that you are trying to use FileUtils.write but an older version (1.4) doesn't have that method (class 'collision')?

Comment: This is the problem which is happening, but root problem is slightly different - the library i'm referencing in my plugin uses newer version of commons-io, whereas run-time provided by gradle provides the older one. So ... gradle should somehow provide separation of ClassLoaders at test-time to let 'own code' and 'plugin code under unit test' coexist with different versions of 3rd party libs.

Comment: Gradle is doing the right thing here and protecting you from having incorrect tests. When you plugin gets loaded its going to run into the same jar miss-match that your tests are seeing. I would try to either use Java8 or Groovy to get around needing this library.

Comment: I would not agree that "Gradle is doing the right thing here". At both "test time" and "run time" internal references (to commons-io in this case) of classes in target plugin should be isolated from internal references of gradle. MAVEN does it for both "test" and "runtime" execution of the plugin code via dedicated ClassLoaders.

Comment: But when the plugin executes it will execute with all of the internal jars loaded first on the classpath. So it's behaving like your plugin will.

Comment: I think you are not getting the right idea, which is implemented in Maven but not implemented in Gradle. When instantiating external plugins, Maven loads their classes via dedicated classloader - it has the classpath filled with JARs referenced in the POM of that plugin. This Classloader has Maven default ClassLoader as parent. This way - local plugin's references are resolved first and default Maven's references - next. Problem of "version collisions" just do not appear that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my initial diagnose about "*Gradle doesn't isolate plugin's classpath from own classpath*" is wrong. The root cause is actually ...

```
dependencies {
    compile gradleApi()
}
```

... ingesting to many dependencies (including commons-io:1.4). And the right solution (at least workable for me) is include only required jars explicitly:

```
versions = [
    gradle: "2.8",
    groovy: "2.4.4",
]

dependencies {
    compile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:${versions.groovy}"
    compile "org.gradle:gradle-base-services:${versions.gradle}"
    compile "org.gradle:gradle-base-services-groovy:${versions.gradle}"
    compile "org.gradle:gradle-core:${versions.gradle}"
    compile files("lib/gradle-platform-jvm-${versions.gradle}.jar")
}
```

Notes:

- gradle's core dependencies should be referenced via public artifact IDs (not via direct JAR file references). This way gradle at run-time uses associated POMs to build transitive run-time dependencies. Otherwise you'll get NoClassDefFoundError during execution of unit tests because other gradle's internals are not in execution classpath.
- it looks like not all gradle's artifacts are available in public repositories (jcenter). If in your plugin you are going to build dependencies on other 'native' tasks (like 'jar') - their implementation has to be referenced directly via JAR file.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

Don't use commons-io:2.1, either use Java8, Groovy, or make a helper to use instead of commons-io.

**Explination**

The root cause is that `gradleApi()` includes commons-io:1.4 and when the test is executing you end up having two commons-io jars on the classpath and the 1.4 version happens to be earlier so that's why your getting a `NoSuchMethodError`.

This happens because Gradle doesn't isolate each plugin in a separate classloader like Maven does. Given how Gradle works you can't. This is because in Gradle a good design strategy is to have multiple plugins that chain together to do one thing. You have one plugin that configures things to be generic and without opinions on how you will use it. Then you have a very opinionated plugin that configures a project with a lot of assumptions. This is helpful when a user doesn't share the same opinions as you do, they can just apply the base plugin and apply their own opinions.

With a more concrete example is you have a jar that contains an [extension](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#N17436) that other plugins use. This could be something like "failBuildOnQualityError". Then each of the separate plugins (using different coordinates) would try to use that extension to see if they should fail the build when checkstyle, findbugs, jacoco, etc find issues.

Comment: "Don't use commons-io:2.1" says don't use any library using "commons-io:2.1", which consequently means - rewrite that whole library "either using Java8, Groovy, ..." what is of course unacceptable.

Comment: The alternative is to make a main class that then inside a javaexec loads a completely seperate classloader where you can add any jar you want.